# I need to pass a user input variable as this list eg: [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2] in below python program. Could some one help me

Tags: python

```
def solution(A):
    sortedset= set(sorted(A))
    sol=1
    #for i in sortedset
    print(sortedset)
    for i in sortedset:
        if i == sol:
           sol+=1
        else:
            break
    print(sol)
A = input()
solution(A)

#A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]
```

''While passing  A = input() and input [1,3,6,4,1,2] not getting expected output '5' but if I give instead of user input directly like as
A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2] i'm getting output '5'. Please help me to fix this issue.
''

Comment: `input` *always returns a string*

Comment: use input().split()

Comment: More than that, use `A = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`

Comment: Separately, sets are always unordered.  There's no point in sorting A before creating a set.  And a set can only contain one of each item, so it's silly to count them.

Comment: if you need A to have [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2] as input, you might have to a split based on a delimiter like : ** A = input().split(',') ** for the input  `"1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2"`. input always returns a string only. BTW you still need to cast it to int type if you want to sort based on value.

Comment: Use @TimRoberts approach. Thats the one i'm suggesting. Add a delimiter in the split method. He has used the default space as delimiter

Comment: The above all answers are not working for me!

Comment: use `A=list(map(int, input().split()))`

Comment: Look, here's the thing: you haven't told us what you're trying to do.  What's the point of this program?

Comment: A given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.
I'm writing program for the above question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the string interpretation of a list that `input` returns to a list with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

A = ast.literal_eval(input())
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Mr. RJ Adriaansen .The above  solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As some people mentioned in the comments, the input function always returns a string.

However if you can always convert this string into your desired type. For example:

1. Using a try block to handle the exception

```
A = []
  try: 
    while True:
      A.append(int(input()))
  # if the input is not-integer, run the function
  except:
    solution(A)
```

2. Using list comprehension:

```
A = [int(item) for item in input("Enter the list items separated by space: ").split()]
solution(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work in python2 but not in 3 as the input is python 2's raw input and python 2's input has been removed

you could use eval(input()) instead

Comment: Please never suggest using `eval` if you don't mention the giant risks of `eval` for the security and integrity of your IT system. Must read: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want I believe: i) string representation of list -> list ii) elements of list -> int

```
import ast
x = '[ "1", "2", "3" , "4", "5"]'
x = ast.literal_eval(x)
x = [int(val) for val in x ]
print(x)
```

> > [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]